# If conditional in visual fox pro

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am not a visual fox pro developer, I work whit python, but I in the task to pass a complete program from VFP to django, so far I didn't have much problem but this conditional appears and I don't know what does it mean, I look for this in internet but any of the results gave a clear answer.
vxSeries is a variable that only contains string and could be in this way 'EF001-01254585960000'
`IF 'E' $ vxSerie OR 'F' $ vxSerie`

Answer (score 3):

It is a plain If condition check that is available in any language including python, strange you couldn't find any clear answer.

```
IF 'E' $ vxSerie OR 'F' $ vxSerie
```

Probably it is the $ operator that fooled you. It is an operator in VFP, that means  X exists in Y - "Y contains X" (where X = 'E' and Y = vxSerie). So:

```
'E' $ vxSerie
```

means, is there any 'E' character in whatever the vxSerie variable is holding at that moment (that variable is not explicitly aliased, might be a field or memory variable).

If

```
vxSerie =  'EF001-01254585960000'
```

then

```
IF 'E' $ m.vxSerie OR 'F' $ m.vxSerie
```

would be true. It is looking if either E or F is available in that string (and shortcutting on first part finding E, second part is not evaluated at all).

(Note that I added m. to mean it is a memory variable explicitly.)